# Outlook OST files not backed up by VSS engine

Tags: microsoft-outlook, backup, volume-shadow-copy

I just found, to my user's annoyance, that Windows VSS engine ignores Outlook's .OST files. This is set by default in the registry here,

[image]

and acknowledged at,

https://kb.acronis.com/content/48032

https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.000085242

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Backup/registry-keys-for-backup-and-restore

The availability of an old copy of the OST files has come handy in the past where the messages on the Exchange server had expired but were available in the old OST.

*So my question is, can anyone see any reason why I shouldn't remove the .ost registry entry assuming storage space is not an issue?*

Comment: You can remove the .ost registry but it's not recommended. OST file is an offline copy of the server data. Normally, when an OST file got corrupted, you can just re-sync a new one from the mail server. Moreover, the OST cannot be reused. You have to find a 3rd-party converter to convert the OST file to PST, then open the PST file instead.

Comment: @SteveFan Thanks Steve. I am aware what OST files are. Due to the company policy, or incopetence, they are unable to restore expired emails. My thinking is to restore local OST as a workaround... BTW, you dont need a OST to PST converter. Just, create Outlook profile, restore OST and make sure Outlook doesnt connect to the server, then export to PST. Voila! I've done it before.